# Photo Competition 2022-06-06: Reflections

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Reflections

The theme of this contest is simple: photos where mirrors, windows, water, or other reflective surfaces were used to get reflections.

This theme was suggested by [Eric S](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/60648/eric-s).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129502/photo-competition-2022-06-06-reflections?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on June 20, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

- The next theme will probably be [Straight out of camera](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7123/) (first ran on February 15, 2021).

Good luck!

**Previous contest**: [2022-04-25: Star Trail](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129205/)

Comment: Why have we stopped using themes suggested in the new suggestions thread? https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/photo-of-the-week-theme-ideas

Comment: @spikey_richie Because pretty much all of the [previously used ones are superior](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7211/15871) to any of the ones still unused?

Comment: @MichaelC My geometric one is pretty super, imho...

Comment: I think straight out of the camera is one of the worse ones, because it gives new cameras and powerful smartphones unfair advantage. SOOC JPEGs from my old Canon 400D are quite unusable most of the time because of weird color casts and no details in highligts nor shadows. OTOH JPEGs coming from my much newer Sony camera are pretty beautiful as they are, not to mention there is a lot more settings affecting the JPEG

Answer (score 53):

[image]

**Foggy Morning**

Bled lake, Slovenia, 24 May 2022
Sony A7R III, Tamron 28-75 G2
f/14.0 1/13s ISO100, 40mm

I hate waking up early in the morning, but the forecast said that there was a high chance of fog, so I bit the bullet and set my alarm clock to 4.45 AM. I'm so glad I did it. The day before there were thousands of tourists. That morning, there was not a person, everything was perfectly still. The silence being only occasionally disturbed by some of the catfishes living in the lake surfacing. What a magical morning it was.

Answer (score 35):

[image: A Gator.]

**Gator waiting for dinner to come by**
Florida, 2015, Canon T3i, 300mm, ISO320, f/9, 1/500s, 300

I love this shot because it's hard to see what you see in the first moment. It seems to be some abstract stuff, until the gator is recognizable.

Comment: Is the water color a real reflection of the sunset or was that edited after the fact?

Comment: It is real, I didn't do anything to it.

Comment: That's... spectacular!

Answer (score 30):

**Cubist Chrysler**

[image]

The Chrysler Building reflecting off another office building along 42nd Street.

Manhattan, New York City, December 2016.

Canon EOS 6D, 85mm, f/3.5, 1/3200 second

Answer (score 26):

[image: Calm Loch Laggan]

**A Calm Loch Laggan**

Loch Laggan, Scotland, April 2018 
Sony A7-II 
Sony FE 24-240mm 
F9, 85mm, 1/320, ISO 200

Answer (score 25):

[image: fall foliage in Maine]

**Fall Foliage in Maine**
2018, Shot with a Canon T3i, 10mm, ISO 100, f/9, 1/320s

Some little lake in Maine's backcountry. The colors were blowing us away.

Answer (score 25):

[image: Fashion Reflection]
**Fashion Reflection**

New York City, around 2008

*Hasselblad 500 C/M | 50mm f/4.0 | Ilford HP-5*

Comment: I love the way the B&W makes the two images fade into each other more completely.

Comment: Square format is my phone camera's only saving grace

Answer (score 23):

[image]

**Cloudy Sunset**

Taken on a small(ish) island in the North Sea, Germany (August 2020).

Nikon D5300 with the Kit 18-55mm lens @ 18mm, f/13.0, 1.3s, ISO100

---

It had been raining the days before I took this picture, so there were many small and larger ponds on the beach which gave this nice reflection.

Answer (score 20):

**Ferris wheel on the pier**

[image: Ferris wheel reflecting into the water]

August 2019, Seattle, Washington

iPhone X, 28mm, f1.8, ISO 80, 1/6s

Answer (score 17):

[image: An accidental self-portrait]

**An accidental self-portrait**

Barcelona, Spain.
December 2009.
Canon G10 <del>(unknown settings: I can't find the original file).</del>  I just stumbled across the original:
Canon PowerShot G10, f/2.8, 1 sec., ISO 800, +2 step exposure, 6mm FL.

After a cancelled flight led to the airline taking me to a hotel for the night, I took this from the window of the room without realising how much the longer shutter speed would reveal the reflection.
I liked how it turned out and it's been my profile picture ever since.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Sunrise on Nile near to Edfu]
**Sunrise on Nile near to Edfu**
Egypt, September 2018,
Canon EOS 5D Mark III,
Sigma 24-105/F4
F4, 24mm, 1/2000s, ISO 100

Answer (score 12):

[image: Extraterrestrials reflect on space and time]

**Extraterrestrials<sup>1</sup> reflect on space and time**

Northern Taiwan, May 2022

iPhone SE-2, automatic

Models: [OPEN-chan](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPEN%E5%B0%8F%E5%B0%87) (checking the time) and [LOCK-chan](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/654/7982) (looking off into space)

<sup>1</sup>OPEN-chan is an extraterrestrial dog from OPEN planet, and LOCK is one from LOCK planet. They traveled to Earth separately in an intergalactic spaceships and made their new home here.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Lights reflecting off the face of a small clock]

### Lights reflecting on a clock

Taken June 2020, Canon Rebel T6 with a 35mm macro lens

Answer (score 11):

[image]

**Roadtrip through Scotland**

Trossachs National Park, Scotland, March 2020
Canon 1100D with wide-angle lens

Decided to go from Marseille, France to Aberdeen Scotland by car to visit a friend. On the outward journey, we wanted to go see some Scotland lakes and liked the scenery here, decided to take my camera and take a shot

Answer (score 11):

[image: Summer morning at Elfin Lakes in Garibaldi Provincial Park, BC, Canada]

**Summer morning at Elfin Lakes in Garibaldi Provincial Park, BC, Canada**

Shot with Canon EOS 7D,1/400,f5.6,ISO 100
Lens: Canon 24-105L @32mm

Mornings like this make me glad I carried all my photography gear in my backpack up to get beautiful nature shots.

*Atwell peak is the peak in the background.

Answer (score 10):

[image: who are you?]

Who are you?

Canon 7DmkII, 1/500, f7.1, ISO100
Lens: Canon EF100-400 @400mm

Young gosling checking out the reflection in the water at the edge of Burnaby Lake in Burnaby, BC, Canada.

He’s not sure if he found a friend or competitor.

Answer (score 9):

**Bank Bank of America Tower Tower**

[image]

42nd Street & 6th Avenue, New York City, September 2013
Canon EOS 400D, Zeiss Distagon 28mm, f/6.3, 1/320 second

The Bank of America Tower on 42nd Street reflecting it's neighbor across 42nd Street reflecting the Bank of America Tower...

Answer (score 9):

**Louise**

[image: Louise]

This was shot with a film camera : Yashica FX-3, with the 50mm lens. Aperture I don't remember.

This was May 7th 2022 in Étalle (South of Belgium) during a WW2 reconstitution. The name "Louise" was hand-painted on the truck. Louise is also the name of my daughter.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Dappled]

**Dappled**

Birmingham, UK
June 2021
iPhone 11, 26mm (wide camera)

Comment: I love this so much. It _looks_ overprocessed with selective brightness just for the underside of the bridge. But I know it's not, it's just the reflected light upwards. It messes with the mind so perfectly.

Comment: Beautiful!! I wish I could have linked here when I wrote about [caustics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/637662/83380) last year.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Monterey State Beach, Monterey, CA]

**Monterey State Beach**

Monterey, CA. July 5, 2017

Canon 5D3, 28mm, ISO 200 f/8 1/320

A small pond that isn't usually there had formed between the parking lot and the berm the people are standing on, so I stopped and waited for some birds. ;)

Answer (score 6):

**Fall colors**
[image: Fall trees reflected on a lake]

Went on a trip to Maine to see fall colors in Maine. Took this walking around around our Airbnb, a farm.

Sony a7ii with 24-70mm kit lens

- f/5.6
- 1/640s
- 28mm
- ISO1000

Answer (score 6):

**Driving home at dusk**

[image: Reflection of a sunset in a car mirror]

March 2021, Pennsylvania

iPhone X, 28mm, f1.8, ISO 25, 1/120s

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**No Window**

June 2022, Motorola G10, 1/539 s, f 1.7, 4.7 mm

A country house in Denmark in the evening. Sun shines through some trees and bushes to the left. Reflections from a window to the right.

Answer (score 4):

**Juvenile swan**

[image: Juvenile swan]

OLYMPUS CORPORATION E-M10 Mark III,ƒ/9, 1/640, 102 mm, ISO800. 40-150 kit lens.

Taken in the fall of 2021 at Compton Verney.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Very Energetic Gull**

Lordship Recreation Ground, London
27 May 2022

A7iii, Sigma 100-400mm F5-6.3 DG DN OS,
377mm, f/6.3, 1/1600s, ISO 2000

Answer (score 4):

[image: Hawke's bay beach, Khi, Pk]
Amazing view of waves hitting the sea-shore **reflecting** the beautiful morning sunlight ☀️

Hawke's Bay Beach, Karachi, Pakistan
 November 28, 2021

Redmi Note 7, Xiomi
ISO 160 | ƒ/1.8 | 1/95822s | 4.74mm

Answer (score 3):

**Sky filled pond**

[image]

Taken in Germany, Fulda on the 30th of may 2021. Shot on a iphone 12 mini with the 14mm ultrawide lens.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Mountain Nanda Devi reflection in Auli Lake, Uttarakhand, India.**

`Captured Date :` 20 Dec, 2021

`Phone :` OnePlus
`Model :` A5010
`Flash :` No flash
`ISO :` 125
`Aperture :` f/1.7
`Focal Length :` 4.10 mm

Comment: Works better with the caption in the description, rather than placed into the image.

Answer (score 2):

**Three Cliffs Bay**

[image: Three Cliffs Bay]

https://goo.gl/maps/3bmXUiurducZN5P59 taken here as a pano, looking from the sea back towards the cliffs.

OLYMPUS CORPORATION E-M10 Mark III, 25 mm prime stitched in-body.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Osaka skyline**

Just the skyline outside Osaka castle on 2019/3/31.

Shot with ZTE Axon 7 A2017G. ISO 100, 1/432, F1.8

Answer (score 0):

Taken at our open mic night by pointing my android at the full-length mirror on the wall.

Hence the entire shot is (literally) a mirror-reflection of the scene.

No big deal except that when I offered it to the online group as a "What's wrong with this picture?" puzzle, *nobody* worked out that it was mirror-reversed from how it would be had I just snapped the scene normally.

[image]

**Bohemia Backwards**

Comment: Left-handed guitarist? I was art director for a magazine. I had to review, select, and process photos. One came in that looked a bit strange to me. It was of some goats lying down in a field. Then it hit me: all the goats were on their *left* side! Goats almost always lie down on their right side, because their rumen (on the left) cannot function properly if they lay on that side.